# Recurring Billing

Tags: magento-1.9, recurring

Is there a solution available in Magento CE 1.9.x through extension(s) or third party where recurring products and regular products (non recurring) can be added to a Magento cart and checkout can proceed normally?

Everything I have found so far limits recurring items to be sold separately from non-recurring and only 1 recurring item at a time can be placed in the cart for checkout. This seems to be such a bad solution for a company selling various kinds of products.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320877/recurring-profile-and-bundled-item and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688612/how-to-add-recurring-profile-and-simple-product-to-cart

Answer (score 1):

You could try a third party system like [Subscribe Pro](http://www.subscribepro.com/features/#features-list). Full disclaimer I have never actually used this services but I think it will cover your needs.

The provider is very open to questions and also offers demos, though the service is expensive.